# How to generate a PKCSs#12 file given private key and certificate in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a base64 encoded private key and public certificate. My requirement is to create a keystore from it. From my analysis, there is no such API in Golang to create it. The other way is to generate a PKCSs#12 format file which is a keystore.

Please let me know the solution if any.

Answer (score 2):

The package [`crypto/pkcs12`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12) provides some basic functions for reading PKCS#12 files (it was imported from [`Azure/go-pkcs12`](https://github.com/Azure/go-pkcs12), but there is currently no way to write them.

The [recommended solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/oni2Fce6ELY), for now, is use OpenSSL.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private.key -in certificate.pem -certfile intermediates.crt -out certificate.pfx
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [go-pkcs12](https://software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12) but it's not clear what should you do with the resulting `[]byte` (write them, I guess?), specially since you can't provide the alias. So I guess that as Simone says, we should stick to `openssl pkcs12`.